# Using wavesurfer.js locally in a Django app

Tags: wavesurfer.js

I downloaded wavesurfer.js from GitHub and added the folder in my django app. I searched through the folders and subfolders but couldn't find the wavesurfer.min.js or whatever the JavaScript file is. I want to be able to add the JavaScript to my HTML template.

I need help with this as I don't want to use the CDN link. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

## [Look here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/)

**Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS.**

1. go in to your static folder
2. copy js file from download folder to this static folder
3. if you don't have static folder > create folder call "static" inside app folder
4. add static root and static url settings to settings.py

   ```
   STATIC_URL = "static/"
   ```
5. add static urls to project urls.py for debug = true

   ```
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.conf.urls.static import static

   urlpatterns = [
       # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
   ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   ```
6. add `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "relative path to your js file from static folder /my_external_script.js" %}"></script>`

Comment: yes. goto CDN , download it , locate it in file system, move it.

Comment: The file is not there in the folders.

Comment: what do you mean? use chrome?

Comment: It's about downloading files. not Django or programming.

Comment: I mean the file wavesurfer.min.js is not in the downloaded folder and that's the file I should link to from the <head> section of my HTML file

Comment: Maybe it did not actually download, because some browsers do not let users download arbitrary js files and  Some antivirus software can sometimes delete them.